# how to make an updatable model in QML

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2

I'm trying to make a QML widget that is interactive and will update its model.

Directly modifying the model does not work, so I create a `updateModel(int index, real x, real y)` signal in `InteractiveGraph`.
However the change done in `onUpdateModel` produces no effect on the UI.

I also tried with an `onUpdateModel` handler such as this: `{ var newModel = model.slice(); newModel[index].x = x; newModel[index].y = y; model = newModel }` but the result is even worse as it breaks the self-dragging of the vertex item, and the model is not updated in the UI anyway.

Is the `Array` class not a good model for this use-case?
Is there some readymade model that is more appropriate?

[image: Application screenshot]

**InteractiveGraph.qml**:

```
import QtQuick 2.0

/* An interactive undirected graph, whose vertices are draggable */

Item {
    id: root
    property alias model: repeater.model
    property real size: 20
    signal updateModel(int index, real x, real y)

    Canvas { // render lines connecting the vertices
        anchors.fill: parent
        onPaint: {
            var ctx = getContext("2d")
            ctx.beginPath()
            for(var i = 0; i < model.length; i++) {
                if(i === 0) ctx.moveTo(model[i].x, model[i].y);
                else ctx.lineTo(model[i].x, model[i].y);
            }
            ctx.closePath()
            ctx.stroke()
        }
    }

    Repeater { // instantiate items corresponding to vertices
        id: repeater
        delegate: Rectangle {
            id: self
            color: "red"
            border.color: "#000"
            width: size
            height: size
            x: modelData.x - size/2
            y: modelData.y - size/2
            Text { anchors.centerIn: parent; text: index }
            MouseArea { // make items self-draggable
                anchors.fill: parent
                drag.target: self
            }
            // invert the x and y relation, and send back the change to model
            onXChanged: root.updateModel(index, x + size/2, y + size/2)
            onYChanged: root.updateModel(index, x + size/2, y + size/2)
        }
    }
}
```

**main.qml**:

```
import QtQuick 2.12
import QtQuick.Window 2.12

Window {
    id: root

    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    InteractiveGraph {
        id: interactiveGraph
        anchors.fill: parent
        model: [
            {x: 15, y: 20},
            {x: 100, y: 220},
            {x: 145, y: 230},
            {x: 225, y: 130},
            {x: 140, y: 88},
            {x: 290, y: 60},
        ]
        onUpdateModel: { model[index].x = x; model[index].y = y; model = model; }
    }
}
```

Comment: as I know a complicated data property doesn't update if its internal state changed. try `var model = view.model; view.model = model`, i.e. just reassign the model to the item itself. yes, that sounds a bit stupid but should work.

Comment: @folibis: tried that and it doeesn't work

Answer (score 0):

I should have read [Models and Views in Qt Quick](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-modelviewsdata-modelview.html), to find out the appropriate model to use is [`ListModel`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtqml-models-listmodel.html).

<s>The only caveat is that we can't use `x`/`y` property names inside the `ListElement` child of `ListModel`, as when using `ListElement`, the variable `modelData` is not used anymore, but directly the property name is exposed, and `x`/`y` would collide with delegate's properties with the same name.</s>

(In case of name clash, we can use `model.fieldName` instead of `fieldName`.)

**InteractiveGraph.qml**:

```
Item {
    id: root
    property alias model: repeater.model
    property real size: 20
    Canvas {
        id: canvas
        anchors.fill: parent
        onPaint: {
            var ctx = getContext("2d")
            ctx.fillStyle = "#eee"; ctx.fillRect(0, 0, width, height)
            ctx.beginPath()
            for(var i = 0; i < model.count; i++) {
                var item = model.get(i)
                if(i === 0) ctx.moveTo(item.xPos, item.yPos)
                else ctx.lineTo(item.xPos, item.yPos)
            }
            ctx.stroke()
        }
    }
    Repeater {
        id: repeater
        delegate: Rectangle {
            id: self
            color: "red"; border.color: "#000"
            x: xPos - size/2; y: yPos - size/2; width: size; height: size
            onXChanged: canvas.requestPaint(); onYChanged: canvas.requestPaint()
            Text { anchors.centerIn: parent; text: index }
            MouseArea {
                anchors.fill: parent
                drag.target: self
                onPositionChanged: model.set(index, {xPos: self.x + size/2, yPos: self.y + size/2})
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**main.qml**:

```
import QtQuick 2.12
import QtQuick.Window 2.12

Window {
    id: root
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    ListModel {
        id: graphModel
        ListElement {xPos:  15; yPos:  20}
        ListElement {xPos: 100; yPos: 220}
        ListElement {xPos: 145; yPos: 230}
        ListElement {xPos: 225; yPos: 130}
        ListElement {xPos: 140; yPos:  88}
        ListElement {xPos: 290; yPos:  60}
    }

    InteractiveGraph {
        id: interactiveGraph
        anchors.fill: parent
        model: graphModel
    }
}
```